# Error when adding a value to a map with specified key

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key

I'm trying to write a method that when invoked will take two arguments, the value to be inserted and the key into which the value will be added.

So far I have come up with the code below:

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Which signature has your `map`?

Comment: There is no method `add(Set<String>)` in class `String`. I think you wanted `map.add(...)`.

Comment: You should need to read [Official Java Document for Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 0):

String does not have "add" method..

```
"cannot find symbol - method add(java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)"
```

hence the exception --remove that line

If your values are "set of other values" than you need to

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
      //Map<key,    value>
public void addValue(String key, Set<String> value)
{
   map.put(key,value);
   System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends which signature has your map. It looks that *you have some problem with it.*

But you can't add smt to `String`. You code want to achieve:

> "here is some string".add("another string")

Compiler doesn't let to do this.

You must to use `add()` from your `map`:

> map.put(key, value);

***UPDATE:***

I tried to recreate all details of code and it works fine:

```
public class Test {
    private static HashMap<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addValue(String key, Set<String> value) {
        Set<String> stringSet = map.get(key);
        if (stringSet != null) {
            updateSet(key, value, stringSet);
            return;
        }
        map.put(key, value);
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }

    private static void updateSet(String key, Set<String> value, Set<String> stringSet) {
        stringSet.addAll(value);
        map.put(key, stringSet);
        System.out.println(stringSet);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addValue("hello", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("world", "duck", "dog")));
        addValue("hello", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("flip")));
        addValue("hello", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("flop")));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
[duck, dog, world]
[duck, dog, flip, world]
[flop, duck, dog, flip, world]
{hello=[flop, duck, dog, flip, world]}
```

*I can't explain strange behavior of your error at this case.*

Comment: I'll try to be more clear about what I have written. I'll edit my post and add more of my code

Comment: There, I hope that's more useful. In its current form the class does compile. Not sure if it is correct as I am not sure how to invoke it to test it.

Comment: @JackB strange behavior. I updated answer according to new data. I made map static to get rid of creating class instance.

Comment: that's almost what I'm looking for. correct me if im wrong but your code seems to be adding a set of strings to a provided key? what I need is to add a single value to an existing key, If that makes any sense

Comment: And i need to be able to call the method from outside the class

Comment: @JackB at this line `map.put(key, value);` we add to map key and link to appropriate value (at this case it is set of strings). If you call again this method with the same key, it updates your ***linked set of strings*** according to this key. `need to be able to call the method from outside the class` make it public it should be enough.

Comment: So suppose I wanted to add the value "Flip" to the key "Rex", how would I do that?

Comment: @JackB With our method it will be `addValue("Rex", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Flip")));`. If change line from my example code output will be: `[Flip]  {Rex=[Flip]}`

Comment: ah thats great, but it has deleted all of the other values, is there a way to keep them and just add "Flip" to the list?

Comment: Any idea? you've almost got it

Comment: @JackB I updated my code snippet. It solves this tricky place.

Comment: @JackB it's kind of you "accept" the answer that resolved your issue, cheers!

Comment: hmm sorry man, but when I try to compile I get a similar error. this time It says it cannot find the symbol 'updateSet'. Anyway you could edit my code to show what you've done?

Comment: @JackB I added this new method below `addValue()`. You must be attentive.

Comment: And what is the argument I use for stringSet when invoking the method? thank you for your patience, it's been a long day